ValueError: Cannot use a compiled regex as replacement pattern with regex=False
I'm doing a project, on Google Colab, where I use the following version:
!pip install "gensim==4.2.0" !pip install "texthero==1.0.5"
Until recently, I received the following warning:
FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
return input.str.replace(r"^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " ")
But the execution worked normally. Now, I'm getting the following error:

How should I proceed?
I tried different versions, but the problem persists.

This is a pandas error, make sure to update your modules. The hero.clean function should use regex=True explicitly since the default changed to False. If the latest version fails, report a bug to texthero.

This is a texthero bug triggering a pandas error.
Pandas str.replace now uses regex=False by default:
Texthero's replace_digits function hasn't been updated in two years and doesn't explicitly pass regex=True:
    if only_blocks:
        pattern = r"\b\d+\b"
        return s.str.replace(pattern, symbols)
    else:
        return s.str.replace(r"\d+", symbols)

You should fill a bug report to texthero, there are probably several other occurrences of str.replace to fix.
In there meantime you can patch the library by changing the code to:
    if only_blocks:
        pattern = r"\b\d+\b"
        return s.str.replace(pattern, symbols, regex=True)
    else:
        return s.str.replace(r"\d+", symbols, regex=True)

Or use a pandas version prior to 2 (e.g. 1.5.2)
